# How to make this grid layout

Tags: ios, storyboard

I need this grid layout, view structure with Storyboard. Is it an easier way to set up, or I need to calculate size / 4, and multiply it by the index, and calculate the center X, Y coordinates, and adjust `NSLayoutConstraint` at each rotation?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UIStackView` with default vertical and change it's axis to horizontal in landscape size class , with distribution `Fill-Equally`

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait
    {
        self.stackV.axis = .vertical
    }
    else
    {            
        self.stackV.axis = .horizontal
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know is it possible to change programmatically UIStackView axis by rotation?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfect but we can also handle it by using storyboard.To explain I get 3 `UIView` into a `stack view` with below property.

[image]

Now when I go to `landscape` from `portrait` mode the height of the screen is converting to `compact` from `regular`.So we can change `stack view axis` from `vertical` to `horizontal` according to height change of the screen.below **gif** explain you visually.

[image]

for further information you can visit this [link](https://www.natashatherobot.com/magical-view-rotation-with-stackview/).